# Checking the value while typing in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If say i am having a textbox input and a integer value A then how to check at time of typing the data itself that the value entered in textbox does not exceed A.

Textbox :

```
<input type="textbox" name="mynumber">
```

My script : 
(According to answer by Felix)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <%int n=(Integer)request.getAttribute("n");%>

        var A=<%=n%>;

        $('input[name^=txtDynamic_]').keyup(function () {

        if (+this.value > A) {
            $(this).next().html('Greater than Total shares');
            flag=1;
        }
        else{
                $(this).next().html('');
        }
        });
</script>
```

FORM :

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="stegnographyonshares" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${myK}">
        Enter The  ${i} share number: <input type="text" name="txtDynamic_${i}" id="txtDynamic_${i}" /><span></span>

        <br />
        <br>
        </br>
    </c:forEach> 
        <br></br>
        <INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="file" value="file"> 
        <br></br>
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" value="SAVE">
    </form>
```

Whats problem in this ? the script code is not running and not printing the error message.Please help

Comment: use the key events to register a handler to do whatever you want to do

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am making the web application using jspa nd servlets in java.How to use keyevents please help

Comment: Use the Java Script events

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** event:

```
$('input[name=mynumber]').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length > A) {
        console.log('Toal characters exceed A')
    }        
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PzMK8/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can do:

```
$('input[name=mynumber]').keyup(function() {
    if(+this.value > A) {
        console.log('Number exceed A');
    }        
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PzMK8/2/)**

Comment: am not saying that is length exceed A.am saying if the integer value of textbox exceeds A then with that textbox itself print that it is greater than A

Comment: @user3509463, check out my answer. It does what you want

Comment: @Felix Now what if say i have N textboxes and their names are t1,t2 and so on.and check the same for all while enetering values in them?

Comment: @user3509463 You can use attribute start with selector, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PzMK8/3/

Comment: @user3509463 If you want to put the error beside the textbox, then you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/PzMK8/6/

Comment: @Felix I tried your code but its not working.Please help.I edited the code in my post.Hope you will get to problem soon

Answer (score 1):

```
//length of text
var Count = 10;
//set id of your input mynumber
$("#mynumber").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length() > Count) {  
           $(this).val().subString(0,Count);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var A = 10;
$('[name="mynumber"]').keyup(function () {
    if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > A) {
        alert("More than A");
    } else {
        alert("Less than A");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/2XwEA/)

Comment: if instead of alert i want to display it beside my texbox only then ?

Answer (score 0):

Can even be done using *HTML5 output tag*

```
<form oninput="x.value = parseInt(a.value) > 10 ? 'Greater than 10' : 'Less than 10' ">
<input type="range" id="a" value="">
<output name="x" for="a"></output>
</form>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQLLu/)

#### [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp)